# Replace/override method of an object which is an implementation of an interface in Java

Tags: java

I have an interface which has only one method. I have a static function which receives objects (these objects implement the interface), and I want to override/replace implementation of the method, that is defined in the interface, in objects. What is the best way to do this in Java

```
public class MyClass {

    public interface MyInterface {
         Object myMethod (Object blah);
    }

    public static MyInterface decorator(MyInterface obj) { 
          //I want to return a version of obj
          //with a different implementation of myMethod
          //everything else in obj should be same, except myMethod 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think, [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) classes can be used for that. - But are you sure you really need this kind of 'runtime decoration'?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class with the same interface that delegates all the methods calls yo your object, then you create an anonymous class extending it and override whatever you want

Intercace:

```
Interface MyInterface {
    void m1();
    void m2();
}
```

Delegating class:

```
class MyDelegate implements MyInterface {
    private MyInterface delegate;

    MyDelegate(MyInterface delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    void m1() {
        delegate.m1();
    }

    void m2() {
       delegate.m2();
    }
}
```

In the static method you create an instance of an anonymous class extending `MyDelegate` and override whatever you want, the rest will be run by `obj`

```
static MyInterface wrap(MyInterface obj) {
    return new MyDelegate(obj) {
        void m1() {
            // overrided m1
        }

        // my will eventually get to obj
    };
}
```

Comment: That's not what is asked. The decorator method is static not the interface method.

Comment: Read the comments in the static, he wants to override the interface method `myMethod`

Comment: This is not what OP asked because the returned object is not an instance of the passed-in object type and won't share any behavior with that object **except** for the interface method.

Comment: Well you've changed the answer :) you stated at first that the problem was with you can't override static methods.

Comment: Besides you **can** exactly this with a dynamic proxy in java. See my answer. Your answer now works fine too but changes the questions requirements a bit (not necessarily something bad though)

Comment: I think you were taking this a bit too literally. Regardless, I don't like using a `Proxy` because it has performance impacts.

Comment: Agreed. My answer limits it too a number of interfaces too.

Comment: Yes, can't argue that by using `Proxy` you'll end up with less code, which is a plus.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that generally, without the knowledge of the exact object type you are decorating. If you know it, then you can create a *subclass* of that particular class with the implementation changed. Java's type system just isn't flexible enough to mix and match interface implementation like you need.

You **could** resort to dynamic class definition techniques, which would create a dynamic proxy for every object you pass into your `decorate` method, but there's an order of magnitude more complexity in such an approach.

Answer (score 1):

Such kind of dynamic behavior is not directly supported in Java. But you can achieve something like this when the object cooperates. I.e. it could provide a method to change the implementation of `myMethod`:

```
void changeMethod(MyInterface other) {
    realImpl = other;
}
Object myMethod (Object obj) {
    return realImpl.myMethod(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [CGLib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) you can implements interfaces at runtime.

Example -

```
public class KeySample {
      private interface MyFactory {
         public Object newInstance(int a, char[] b, String d);
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          MyFactory f = (MyFactory)KeyFactory.create(MyFactory.class);
          Object key1 = f.newInstance(20, new char[]{ 'a', 'b' }, "hello");
          Object key2 = f.newInstance(20, new char[]{ 'a', 'b' }, "hello");
          Object key3 = f.newInstance(20, new char[]{ 'a', '_' }, "hello");
          System.out.println(key1.equals(key2));
          System.out.println(key2.equals(key3));
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a dynamic proxy if we can restrict it to interfaces (any number of them).

So your problem: If you call the method in that interface first without calling the decorator and then with the decorator you want different behavior, so given this interface implementation:

```
MyInterface o = new MyInterface() {
    public Object myMethod(Object blah) {
        return "bar";
    }
};
```

This should do different things, for example alter the return value (and/or something else):

```
System.out.println(o.myMethod(null));
o = decorator(o);
System.out.println(o.myMethod(null));
```

Output:

```
bar
foo
```

This can be done with a dynamic proxy in java:

```
public static MyInterface decorator(final MyInterface obj) { 
  InvocationHandler handler = new InvocationHandler() {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
      if (method.getName().equals("myMethod")) {
        //do something special
        return "foo";
      }
      return method.invoke(obj, args);
    }
  };


  MyInterface proxy = (MyInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                            MyInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
                            obj.getClass().getInterfaces(), //all or limit it to just one or a few
                            handler);
  return proxy;
}
```

Update: 
If you want to involve more interfaces (updated proxy instance code above to get the interfaces implemented instead of hard coding it):

Now makes this work:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        A o = new A();
        System.out.println(o.myMethod(null));
        System.out.println(o.myOtherMethod(1));
        Object o2 = decorator(o);
        System.out.println(((MyInterface) o2).myMethod(null));
        System.out.println(((MyInterface2) o2).myOtherMethod(1));
 }
```

With output:

```
bar
2
foo <-- changed
2 <- the same behavior
```

Given:

```
class A implements MyInterface, MyInterface2 {
  @Override
  public Object myMethod(Object blah) {
    return "bar";
  }

  @Override
  public int myOtherMethod(int a) {
    return a+1;
  }
}
```